# Aggregate Result to picklist

Tags: aggregateresult

I have a dropdown in my page.
I have an aggregate query result to be binded to this dropdown. How do I do it?
How can I assign this aggregate result to selectoption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Apex:

```
public String selectOption {get; set;}

public SelectOption[] getOptions() {
    SelectOption[] options = new SelectOption[] {};
    for (AggregateResult ar : [
            select Name n
            from Contact
            group by Name
            order by Name
            ]) {
        String n = (String) ar.get('n');
        options.add(new SelectOption(n, n));
    }
    return options;
}
```

and then in the Visualforce:

```
<apex:selectList value="{!selectedOption}" size="1">
   <apex:selectOptions value="{!options}"/>
</apex:selectList>
```